# How to switch 2 elements in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I will start with an example (I think it will show exactly my problem)

```
switch 1 2 [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,0,7]] -> [[1,2,0,4],[5,6,3,7]]
```

Where [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,0,7]] !! 1 !! 2 is the zero element. The first integer is always 1 and the second one ranges between 0 and 3 and I want to change the element I give as parameter through his indexes (from the second component list) with the element from the same position in the first component list.

I know the lists are immutable in Haskell, however I still can't figure it out.

How can I do this?

Comment: Lists are immutable, right. But you can construct new ones from other lists.

Comment: Also, if first integer is always 1 why would you pass it? In your example it looks pretty pointless. You can start by defining function `switch :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])` so you don't mess with sublists expansion in this function.

Comment: @d12frosted I can switch the elements both ways, but I gave this example  hoping for a explanation and once I understand how it's done, I suppose it's quite easy for me to adjust the function so it works fine both ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch i j l = [a,b]
    where (a,b) = unzip [if j==n then (l!!1!!n, l!!0!!n) else (l!!0!!n,l!!1!!n) | n<-[0..3]]
```

the first integer is useless

Answer (score 4):

```
switch _ n [xs,ys] = [xs',ys']
   where (xs',ys',_) = unzip3 $ 
                       map (\t@(x,y,m) -> if m==n then (y,x,m) else t) $
                       zip3 xs ys [0..]
```